# Can't access some of the object properties PHP (RedBeanPhp object)

Tags: php, object, properties, get, redbean

I have var_dump of my object. Here is the output. In my code object is $d->depositType. When I echo $d->depositType->id or $d->depositType->years I get the values I want. But when I try to get to $d->depositType->name or $d->depositType->name I get null. Could somebody please help me.Thanks in advance.

```
    object(RedBean_OODBBean)[47]
      private 'flagSkipBeau' => boolean false
      private 'properties' => 
        array (size=4)
          'id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'Name' => string 'Year Deposit' (length=12)
          'Percentage' => string '10.00' (length=5)
          'years' => string '1' (length=1)
      private '__info' => 
        array (size=4)
          'type' => string 'depositType' (length=11)
          'sys.id' => string 'id' (length=2)
          'sys.orig' => 
            array (size=4)
              'id' => string '1' (length=1)
              'Name' => string 'Year Deposit' (length=12)
              'Percentage' => string '10.00' (length=5)
              'years' => string '1' (length=1)
          'tainted' => boolean false
      private 'beanHelper' => 
        object(RedBean_BeanHelper_Facade)[21]
      private 'fetchType' => null
      private 'withSql' => string '' (length=0)
      private 'withParams' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      private 'aliasName' => null
      private 'via' => null
      private 'writeOnly' => boolean false
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP is case sensitive to variables: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php

`$d->depositType->name` does not exists.

`$d->depositType->Name` does.

Comment: It still gives me null